# UITableView multiple section with multiple dictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to work out on this scenario and just curious if it's possible to have multiple sections in one `UITableView` with with multiple `NSDictionary` contents? I have been trying to figure this and see if someone have had encountered this issue and how did s/he could get it resolved?

I have segregated count in `numberOfRowsInSection` method, but at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I am having some issues with respect to how to segregate the sections with different dictionaries.

Comment: Are you using an index style table view, like in the iPhone contacts app?

Comment: No, I am just using simple table view which I am populating from the json I am getting. So initially I have a dictionary in which I have sets of 2 array, which have different naming convention but the properties within the array for both conventions are the same, like for ex: Dictionary (People) -> man (name, address, phone) & woman (name, address, phone). Now I am trying to sectionize these two contents on the tableview which is coming from one dictionary but is subset of two different array's under same table view.

Comment: so you have only 2 entry in your dictionary?

Comment: Vince, yes thats correct

Comment: if your arrays are sorted the way you want and each represent a section you got all you need, if you know what is the count of each section, you know how to refer to the different sections, use that same logic in your rowAtIndexPath. The NSIndexPath is like a path to a 2 dimentional array, 1st dimention == section, 2nd dimention == row.

Comment: Vince I see what you are saying now, I will play around with that type later on, at this point I have converged two array into single array and eliminating sections for easier use, but I will try to work around with that soon. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CellForRowAtIndexPath receives the indexPath parameter as an input.  The indexPath.section attribute tells you what section of the table the cell is in, and indexPath.row tells you what row within that section.  If you have a separate dictionary for each section, then you do a switch on indexPath.section, and get the data from the appropriate dictionary for that row.

Comment: Ray, makes sense. I think switch case will make a good sense here.

Comment: Ray, I did got the section segregated with the row its suppose to show, but at the cellForRowAtIndex, I am not sure how do I populate the cells for different section, as it only calls for indexPath than the section.

Comment: @kforkarim indexPath has 2 parts: a section, and a row within that section.  So every row makes a call to cellForRowAtIndexPath, and indexPath.section tells you what section, and indexPath.row tells you what row within that section.  So cellForRowAtIndexPath is going to have a very similar structure to numberOfRowsInSection - they'll both switch on indexPath.section.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are using 1 dictionary per section.

Dictionary are unordered, so you must keep in some way the key in a ordered fashion.
You can put your Dictionary in an array in the order you want to show them.
So that's for the section part of your `NSIndexPath`.

```
aDictionary = [arrayOfDic objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

If you want to display the content of that dictionary in ascending order or your key you can do something like that :

```
anArray = [[aDictionary allKeys] sortedInSomeWayWithSomeSelector];
someObjt = [anArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Then you have the row for your NSIndexPath.
This is pretty generic, you will have to adapt it to your code.
And I would prefer to cache the orderedKey, because sorting at every row would be a waste of resources, but you got the general idea.